# How to convert XBF (XAML Binary Format) to XAML

Tags: windows-8.1

With Windows 8.1 release, there are some new API changes/Added. As per new Addition, there is new feature called as "XAML Binary Format" which will improve performance of rendering on screen. `XamlBinaryWriter` class is responsible to convert into XAML Binary Format.All the XAML files will be converted to XBF. Has Any one Tried in Converting XBF file into XAML File. I have some dependency on XAML File.I cannot proceed without in XAML format. Please let me know how to convert XBF to XAML File.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to include a XAML file in the package, without the build process converting it to XBF? In that case, have you tried setting the `Build Action` property of the file to `Content` or `Resource`?

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, download and install Microsoft's [.NetNative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx), the ReducerEngine.dll installed as a part of that thing includes some [primitive implementation](http://xamldecompiler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#XAMLDecompiler/MainWindow.xaml.cs) of the decompiler.

However, the MS' implementation is very poor, it doesn't even support XAML namespaces. You can use the Microsoft's implementation to learn the structure of an XBF file, for decompiling however I suggest you implement your own solution. It's not that hard, mine is about 1000 lines of code in 12 C# files.

XBF files are rather simple. They contain a fixed header, followed by 6 lookup tables (strings, assemblies, type namespaces, types, properties, XML namespaces), followed by the DOM tree part, where objects reference values from those tables by integer keys.

P.S. The most interesting question I have about that, is why did Microsoft choose to reinvent the wheel instead of using their [.NET Binary XML format](http://const.me/articles/net-tcp/) or the subset of it? They have binary XML implementation for many years, and technically it's better format then XBF.